# docker compose inside docker machine, can't mount volume

Tags: django, docker, docker-compose, docker-machine

I have simple website application that is using Django, postgresql. The structure of my little project looks like this:

```
.
├── docker-compose.yml
└── web
    ├── authentication
    ├── bower.json
    ├── Dockerfile
    ├── manage.py
    ├── requirements.txt
    ├── static
    └── trello_copy
```

When i use only docker-compose for build this everything works fine. I created my docker machine and connected to them then i use exactly the same commands as before:

```
docker-compose build
docker-compose up
```

and it turned out that docker had not copied my web folder to web container he just create code folder and web folder inside code but web folder is empty.

docker-compose.yml

```
postgres:
  image: postgres
  volumes:
    - /var/docker/postgresql:/var/lib/postgresql/data
  ports:
    - "5432:5432"

web:
  build: ./web
  volumes:
    - ./web:/code
  ports:
    - "8000:8000"
  links:
    - postgresql:postgresql
  command: bash -c "python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000"
```

Dockerfile

```
FROM python:2.7
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1
RUN mkdir /code
WORKDIR /code
ADD requirements.txt /code/
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
ADD . /code/
```

I need to use docker machine for debugging purpose(PyCharm).

**UPDATE**

I found the solution for this(works only for web). First you need to do is to use sharedfolder in VirtualBox.

```
VBoxManage sharedfolder add <machine_name> --name <mount_name> --hostpath <host_path_to_folder_you_want_to_share>
```

then you have to connect to you docker-machine vm host via ssh and mount this folder.

```
mount -t vboxsf -o defaults,uid=`id -u docker`,gid=`id -g docker` <mount_name> <path_in_you_vm_machine>
```

so now you host folder is mounted in `<path_in_you_vm_machine>` on you vm host but there is another problem. When you reboot the vm host you will have to mount this folder again. From docs
[boot2docker docs](https://github.com/boot2docker/boot2docker/blob/master/doc/FAQ.md#local-customisation-with-persistent-partition)

we can read that there is a script who is executed when vm host is starting. You have to put this command in this file on you vm host

```
/mnt/var/lib/boot2docker/bootlocal.sh
```

for example:

```
mkdir -p <vm_path>
mount -t vboxsf -o defaults,uid=`id -u docker`,gid=`id -g docker` <mount_name> <vm_path>
```

This works well for my web project but when i am using the same approach for postgresql its not working and reason is that mounted folder has different ownership than postgres(Docker in this case) and postgresql will not start.

I found that this problem is considered here [proposal machine share](https://github.com/docker/machine/issues/179)

Comment: Is your project directory inside `C:\users` (Windows) or `/Users` (OS X)? Or located somewhere else on your computer?

Comment: the reason that this doesn't work is that docker machine create vm host who know nothing about my local file system.

When i am using docker-compose the volumes section in docker-compose.yml is pointing to my vm host so this will never work that i want.
I could use docker-machine scp command and copy my project to vm host but this make no sense because i would have to doing this each time when
i changed my source code. 

I tried to share my project folder between my local host and vm host but with no success - vm host didn't see my shared folder.

Comment: Actually, it *does* share the files in your host with the VM; by default, docker machine / boot2docker sets up the virtual machine to share the `C:\Users` / `/Users` directory through virtual box file sharing; https://github.com/boot2docker/boot2docker#folder-sharing